# Laravel 5.5 Don't use route if url has a certain structure

Tags: laravel, routes

First of all, I'm not a server admin by any means, so it might be possible to do this at server level.

I have a Windows server where they added a network drive to the root of the web server. So it's accessible through for example http://127.0.0.1/drivename/path/to/folder (localhost on the server obviously, would be network IP on the intranet).
Thing is, they have a Laravel 5.5 running in that same root and want to link from that Laravel to files on the network drive.

If I just put in a link to "http://127.0.0.1/B/path/to/folder", Laravel will pick it up and throw a 404.

I've tried to get them to upload the files to Laravel, but the files on that network drive are used for other things as well, so it's easier to manage for them if it all stays in the same place.

Is there a way to tell Laravel to ignore get requests with a certain pattern? Or is this something that needs to be done on server level?

I sincerely hope someone can help me with this because I'm lost.

Comment: You could probably change the server configuration that rewrites the URL (possibly `public/web.config`) which checks if a file exists, but I don't know how to do that in Windows. Or you could create a fallback route that reads and returns the file, but this will be a lot worse for performance.

Comment: @Thomas: I think I may have found a way to skip Laravel redirecting it to index.php via .htaccess. Won't know for sure until I get FTP access and can set up the system on their server. What I have: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/C before the Front Controller handle. /C being the drive letter. Only downside is that they'd have to add drive letters manually